# C++ Reading from txt file into object binary tree

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, iostream

***Edited code with my changes--not getting access violation anymore and it's assigning all my values perfectly except for the Customer ID--it's just leaving that blank.  Is that because the ID is numeric and not technically a string??

This is homework--We are supposed to read data from a .txt file, then assign the records to objects, then write the objects to a binary tree.  This is the input text file format:

```
00001
Wilee Caytote
123 E. Fifth St.
Phynox
AZ
12345-1234
00002
Dave Wells
444 W. Third St.
Dayton
OH
45402
00012
Robert U. McKey
4986 Boundary St.
Jacksonville
AZ
12345
00123
Ruby B. Edwards
4861 Spring Ave.
Philadelphia
PA
19108
```

Each line is a member of the Customer (Id, Name, Address) and Address (Street, City, State, Zip) classes.  I am overriding my cin >> operator to take in the values, but the values are not getting assigned to the object members.  I'm sure my program can read the text file because I did the below, and got my file printed to the console.

```
myfile.open ("Customers.txt");
while(getline(myfile, line)) 
    {
cout << line << '\n';
    }
myfile.close();
```

Here is my Customer.h class where the cin overload is:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "Address.h"

using namespace std;

class Customer
{

private:
//Attributes for customers
string custID;
string custName;
Address* address;

public:
//Constructors for Customer
Customer();
Customer(string, string, Address*);
~Customer();
//Setters for Customer
void setCustID(int);
void setCustName(string);
void setCustAddress(Address*);
//Getters for Customer
string getCustID() { return custID; }
string getCustName() { return custName; }

//Operator overloads
bool operator>(Customer obj) { return custID > obj.custID; }
bool operator<(Customer obj) { return custID < obj.custID; }
bool operator==(Customer obj) { return custID == obj.custID; }

//Operator overloads for input
friend istream &operator>>(istream &input, Customer &customer) {
    getline(input, customer.custID);
    getline(input, customer.custName);
    (*customer.address);
    return input;
}

//Operator overloads for output
friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &output, Customer &customer) {
    output << "CustID: " << customer.custID << endl << "Customer Name: " << customer.custName << endl << (*customer.address);
    return output;
}
};
```

Here is my Address.h class:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

class Address 
{
private:
string street;
string city;
string state;
string zip;

public:
//Constructors for address
Address();
Address(string, string, string, string);
~Address();
//Setters for address
void setAddressStreet(string);
void setAddressCity(string);
void setAddressState(string);
void setAddressZip(string);
//Getters for address
string getAddressStreet() {return street;}
string getAddressCity() {return city;}
string getAddressState() {return state;}
string getAddressZip() {return zip;}

//Operator overload for input
friend istream &operator>>(istream &input, Address &address) {
    getline(input, address.street);
    getline(input, address.city); 
    getline(input, address.state);
    getline(input, address.zip);
    return input;
}
//Operator overload for output
friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &output, Address &address) {
    output << "Street Address: " << address.street << endl << "City: " << address.city << endl << "State: " << address.state << endl << "Zip: " << address.zip << endl;
    return output;
}
};
```

Here is my driver where I am reading in the file, and assigning the lines to the objects, and inserting them in the binary tree:

```
#include "Customer.h"
#include "BinaryTree.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()  
{
BinaryTree tree;
Customer customer;
string id;

//Define file and line variables
ifstream myfile;
string line;

//Open file and read lines into objects
myfile.open ("Customers.txt");
while(myfile >> line) 
{
    myfile >> customer;
    tree.addCustomer(customer);
    cout << customer;
}
myfile.close();

system ("pause");
return 0;
```

}

Customer.cpp:

```
#include "Customer.h"

//Customer no arg constructor
Customer::Customer()
{
custID = "";
custName = "";
address = new Address;
}

//Customer constructor
Customer::Customer(string custID, string custName, Address* address)
{
this->custID = custID;
this->custName = custName;
}

//Customer destructor
Customer::~Customer()
{
}
```

Address.cpp:

```
#include "Address.h"

//Address no arg constructor
Address::Address()
{
street = "";
city = "";
state = "";
zip = "";
}

//Address constructor
Address::Address(string street, string city, string state, string zip)
{
this->street = street;
this->city = city;
this->state = state;
this->zip = zip;
}

//Address destructor
Address::~Address()
{
}
```

Comment: You are using `>>` to read fields that contain spaces which is not what you want to do.  You need to use `getline()` for any input that contains a spaces.

Comment: You use getline to read a single line (the first one only containing "00001" and then your overridden Customer >> operator tries to extract ID, name and address from it ?

Comment: Does Customer's default constructor ever initialise the Customer::address pointer ? If not then that would certainly be cause for a memory violation when operator >> uses it.

Comment: @NathanOliver, I guess I thought I was using getline in my while loop in my CustomerMenu.cpp--I guess I'm not!  Like I said, I probably have some logic issues here.  So I need to use getline for each input in my operator overload--right?

Comment: @user1320881, also good points.  I need to use my getline for each line in my cin overload.  As to your second question about initializing the address, I'm posting my cpp files for both classes, can you let me know how to do that?

Comment: The way you have data members and class I would use `getline()` for all of your reads except for when you read the address.  You should still use the `>>` operator for the address and have `getline()` calls in the function.

Comment: EVERY suggestion has worked great--thank you all! I just have one more issue with the Customer ID, for some reason it's not assigning that part of it--see original question--edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize your address pointer in your `Customer` class. You're dereferencing an uninitialized pointer which is causing the access violation exception.

In your `customer` constructor, add the line:

```
address = new Address;
```

You'll need to add the following to the `customer` destructor:

```
delete address;
```

Although, I am curious as to why your `Address` member is a pointer at all. It would be much safer and less error-prone to declare it directly instead of creating a pointer to it. If you really want it to be a pointer I would recommend looking at [std::unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) instead of using a raw pointer.

Comment: Adding an address initialization to my customer constructor got rid of the the access violation error, thanks!  Although, I tried making my address member not a pointer, and then I got all kinds of syntax errors on the = sign.  I put it back to a pointer and everything is happy.